# Exception error while importing lda python function

Tags: python, lda

I am getting an exception error while importing [lda](http://pythonhosted.org/lda/) module. I have installed lda and its dependent packages : Numpy and [pbr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pbr). Hereby I am sharing you the exception output which I got.

```
import lda

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-120-4b4ad2b47765>", line 1, in <module>
    import lda

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\lda\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    __version__ = pbr.version.VersionInfo('lda').version_string()

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pbr\version.py", line 466, in version_string
    return self.semantic_version().brief_string()

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pbr\version.py", line 461, in semantic_version
    self._semantic = self._get_version_from_pkg_resources()

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pbr\version.py", line 448, in _get_version_from_pkg_resources
    result_string = packaging.get_version(self.package)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pbr\packaging.py", line 748, in get_version
    name=package_name))

Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argument given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name lda was given, but was not able to be found.
```

Can someone please help me in this ?

Comment: Are you sure that git is installed?  Also you can try upgrading the distribute module `pip install --upgrade distribute`.

Comment: first install lda using `pip install lda`

Comment: @nishant : I have already installed lda. After that when I am importing lda it is throwing exception

Comment: Did you tried using easy_install?